# Cannot Encrypt/Decrypt String in Powershell

Tags: powershell, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt & decrypt a string with `ConvertTo-SecureString`, output the string plaintext, and verify that the key works correctly to decrypt the string in PowerShell.

I'm expecting it to output "Hello World", but I'm getting an unexpected string instead.

How Can I fix this? I cannot use `Security.Cryptography` classes because this script is designed to run in a restricted execution policy environment where `Add-Type` cannot be used.

```
$encryptionKey = (13, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
$stringToEncrypt = "Hello World"

$stringToEncrypt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $encryptionKey | Out-File -FilePath key.txt


$decrypted = Get-Content key.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $encryptionKey
Write-Host $decrypted # The Decrypted String, expected to be "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very close. It looks like you may have just mixed parameters on the decryption part. With `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `ConvertFrom-SecureString.`

`ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $encryptionKey` will first decrypt your encrypted string and convert to a secure string. `ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText` is then going to convert the secure string back into a plain text string.

Change the line

```
 # change this 
$decrypted = Get-Content key.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString-AsPlainText -Force  | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $encryptionKey

    
# to this
$decrypted =  Get-Content key.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $encryptionKey | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

See the documentation for [ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.3)  and [ConvertTo-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7.3) for some more examples and explanations.